# What is the simplest way to emulate the original gameboy's cpu using Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

My initial question assumes it is possible to emulate the original GameBoy system using an Arduino board.

Additional information in non-technical terms: I am looking to create an Arduino based device that accepts cartridges as input devices (in some cases they will also function as output devices) I am interested primarily in the Hexadecimal/pixel based "logic" which gameboy games uses to display game data.

What is the simplest way to emulate the original gameboy's hexadecimal based pixel logic to fetch, decode, and execute data using Arduino?

Before flagging this question, please comment so that I may clarify as this is a complex question to ask and I am willing to re word it as necessary.

Comment: never assume anything

Comment: `hexadecimal based pixel logic` makes no sense ... it is all binary data

Comment: On an Arduino? No chance. On something more powerful? Sure. I've seen Z80 (and other) emulation running on an ESP32 (see [FabGL](https://github.com/fdivitto/FabGL/tree/master/src/emudevs)), and the Sharp LR35902 the gameboy uses is very similar to the Z80.

Comment: There are multiple open-source emulators. Do your research, and read their documentation and code. You will quickly find that an 8-bit AVR cannot emulate a GB in real-time. (_Note: Many years ago I wrote a GB emulator for a 68000 CPU (16/32 bit system) with 16 MHz. It runs common games with 1/4 to 1/10 of their original speed, and had no sound emulation._)

Comment: @jsotola you are correct at the machine level all operations are binary, but a 1 with 15 leading zeros can be interpreted the same as a 1 with no leading zeros that leaves 15 unique locations available for data manipulation. i'm sorry if it does not make sense to you. imagine a 16 by 16 grid of squares. each one is able to be "colored in" if any square is filled in then it is treated as a 1 rather than a 0 . the placement of these squares along with other factors can be used to store information. the compressed form is seen as hexadecimal code which when uncompressed becomes binary data.

Comment: @Majenko I am not looking to use it to play games, just utilize hex based addressing that functions similarly to how a gameboy game might store and retrieve data from a game cartridge. I believe the frame rate could be much much less than what a typical game would need to be. I would not necessarily need to play sound, though I recall how pokemon each had unique "sounds" or cries when appearing on screen, so sound is still something I am still researching. I will check out the z80 I believe that the docs i read used a teensy 4.0 which worked with most arduino peripherals.

Comment: @thebusybee I will continue researching and hopefully in a few days I can re word this question to better suit my needs. I also read that the esp32 has a dual cores with 240 mhz clock speed for each processor. I may eventually try using this if possible. To clarify I would like to Specifically be able to emulate only a game operating almost identically to Pokemon.

Comment: @PeopleCallMeAdam hexadecimal notation is simply for human readability of binary data ... it is not a compressed version of binary data ... there is no *hex based addressing* ... it is all binary addressing at machine level ... when the processor retrieves a value of 0x48F4, it is actually retrieving 0100100011110100 ... it knows nothing about 0x48F4

Comment: @jsotola again I am aware that the data is binary at the machine level, I view hexadecimal notation as a form of "lossless compression" humans speak many languages, when you translate between them you often lose part of the meaning in that translation. if binary code is the meaning and hardware the "speaker" think of software as people some people/software speak spanish and some speak english. if hexadecimal allowed for a lossless compression of some meaning in english then later uncompressed in spanish with nothing lost during translation with 100% success rate would what i said make sense?

Comment: @PeopleCallMeAdam No, that makes no sense at all (regarding your comment asking, “If hexadecimal allowed for a lossless compression … meaning in English uncompressed in Spanish… would what I said make sense?”).

Answer (score 0):

(Assembling an answer from the comments)

The consensus is that there is no "simple way to emulate the original gameboy cpu using Arduino". That a more powerful platform is required.

Multiple commenters expressed difficulty with the novel concept of "hexadecimal/pixel based logic". It is suggested that this concept may be without merit.